# JSON innerHTML to Javascript ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, news-ticker

I was convert JSON data from external page and trying to use that data in the news ticker.

When I try to use the data created from JSON, the ticker do not work.

When I manually write the same data in the page source, ticker works fine.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="A powerful, flexible and animated vertical news ticker plugin for JQuery, which provides multiple callbacks and methods to allow a maximum flexibility and an easy implementation into any project.">
    <meta name="author" content="risq">
    <title>JQuery Advanced News Ticker | risq</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/css/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>


<h1>Customers</h1>


<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
     var out = '<ul id="nt-example1">';

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<li>' +

        arr[i].Name +
        ' - ' +
        arr[i].City +
        '-' +
        arr[i].Country +
        '</li>';
    }
    out += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

  <div class="green">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 centered">
     <div id="nt-example1-container">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" id="nt-example1-prev"></i>
      <!--                  <ul id="nt-example1">
       <li>Alfreds Futterkiste - Berlin-Germany</li><li>Berglunds snabbköp - Luleå-Sweden</li><li>Centro comercial Moctezuma - México D.F.-Mexico</li>
       <li>Ernst Handel - Graz-Austria</li>
       <li>FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A. - Madrid-Spain</li><li>Galería del gastrónomo - Barcelona-Spain</li><li>Island Trading - Cowes-UK</li>
       <li>Königlich Essen - Brandenburg-Germany</li>
       <li>Laughing Bacchus Wine Cellars - Vancouver-Canada</li>
       <li>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti - Bergamo-Italy</li>
       <li>North/South - London-UK</li><li>Paris spécialités - Paris-France</li><li>Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery - Albuquerque-USA</li>
       <li>Simons bistro - København-Denmark</li><li>The Big Cheese - Portland-USA</li><li>Vaffeljernet - Århus-Denmark</li>
       <li>Wolski Zajazd - Warszawa-Poland</li>
      </ul>  -->
<div id="id01"></div>
                  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" id="nt-example1-next"></i>
              </div>
    </div>
    

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('a[href*=#]').click(function(e) {
       var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
       if (href != "#") {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - 81
        }, 500);
    }
    else {
     $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
    }
       return false;
   });



         // header news ticker
            var nt_title = $('#nt-title').newsTicker({
                row_height: 40,
                max_rows: 1,
                duration: 3000,
                pauseOnHover: 0
            });

            // example 1
            var nt_example1 = $('#nt-example1').newsTicker({
                row_height: 80,
                max_rows: 3,
                duration: 4000,
                prevButton: $('#nt-example1-prev'),
                nextButton: $('#nt-example1-next')
            });

            // example 2
            var nt_example2 = $('#nt-example2').newsTicker({
                row_height: 60,
                max_rows: 1,
                speed: 300,
                duration: 6000,
                prevButton: $('#nt-example2-prev'),
                nextButton: $('#nt-example2-next'),
                hasMoved: function() {
                 $('#nt-example2-infos-container').fadeOut(200, function(){
                  $('#nt-example2-infos .infos-hour').text($('#nt-example2 li:first span').text());
                  $('#nt-example2-infos .infos-text').text($('#nt-example2 li:first').data('infos'));
                  $(this).fadeIn(400);
                 });
                },
                pause: function() {
                 $('#nt-example2 li i').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
                },
                unpause: function() {
                 $('#nt-example2 li i').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
                }
            });
            $('#nt-example2-infos').hover(function() {
                nt_example2.newsTicker('pause');
            }, function() {
                nt_example2.newsTicker('unpause');
            });

            // example 3
            var state = 'stopped';
            var speed;
            var add;
            var nt_example3 = $('#nt-example3').newsTicker({
                row_height: 80,
                max_rows: 1,
                duration: 0,
                speed: 10,
                autostart: 0,
                pauseOnHover: 0,
                hasMoved: function() {
                 if (speed > 700) {
                  nt_example3.newsTicker("stop");
                  $('#nt-example3-button').text("RESULT: " + $('#nt-example3 li:first').text().toUpperCase());
                  setTimeout(function() {
                   $('#nt-example3-button').text("START");
                   state = 'stopped';
                  },2500);
                  
                 }
                 else if (state == 'stopping') {
                  add = add * 1.4;
                  speed = speed + add;
                  nt_example3.newsTicker('updateOption', "duration", speed + 25)
                       .newsTicker('updateOption', "speed", speed);
                 }
                }
            });
            
            $('#nt-example3-button').click(function(){
             if (state == 'stopped') {
              state = 'turning';
              speed = 1;
              add = 1;
              nt_example3.newsTicker('updateOption', "duration", 0)
                   .newsTicker('updateOption', "speed", speed)
                   .newsTicker('start');
              $(this).text("STOP");
             }
             else if (state == 'turning') {
              state = 'stopping';
              $(this).text("WAITING...");
             }
            });
        </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please explain your problem more clearly.. none of your snippet work.

Comment: Do some basic debugging steps. For example, `console.log(JSON.parse(response))` and see if it looks like what it should.

Comment: Utkanos, it looks OK to me. I can not find where is the problem.